# Numpy array creation using a sequence

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I have seen [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10753528/numpy-array-creating-with-a-sequence?noredirect=1&lq=1), but it doesn't quite answer my question.

I have an array:

```
x = np.array([0, 1, 2])
```

I want this:

```
y = np.array([[0,1], [0,2], [1,0], [1,2], [2,0], [2,1]])
```

That is, I want to take each value (let's call it `i`) of the array `x` and create `x.shape[0]-1` new arrays with all of the other values of `x`, excluding `i`.

Essentially `y` contains the indices of a 3x3 matrix without any diagonal elements.

I have a feeling there's an easy, pythonic way of doing this that's just not coming to me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Approach #1 :** One approach would be -

```
x[np.argwhere(~np.eye(len(x),dtype=bool))]
```

**Approach #2 :** In two steps -

```
r = np.arange(len(x))
out = x[np.argwhere(r[:,None]!=r)]
```

**Approach #3 :** For performance, it might be better to create those pairwise coordinates and then mask. To get the paiwise coordinates, let's use [`cartesian_product_transpose`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11146645/3293881), like so -

```
r = np.arange(len(x))
mask = r[:,None]!=r
out = cartesian_product_transpose(x,x)[mask.ravel()]
```

**Approach #4 :** Another with [`np.broadcast_to`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.13.0/reference/generated/numpy.broadcast_to.html) that avoids making copies until masking, again meant as a performance measure -

```
n = len(x)
r = np.arange(n)
mask = r[:,None]!=r
c0 = np.broadcast_to(x[:,None], (n, n))[mask]
c1 = np.broadcast_to(x, (n,n))[mask]
out = np.column_stack((c0,c1))
```

Runtime test -

```
In [382]: x = np.random.randint(0,9,(1000))

# @tom10's soln
In [392]: %timeit list(itertools.permutations(x, 2))
10 loops, best of 3: 62 ms per loop

In [383]: %%timeit
     ...: x[np.argwhere(~np.eye(len(x),dtype=bool))]
100 loops, best of 3: 11.4 ms per loop

In [384]: %%timeit
     ...: r = np.arange(len(x))
     ...: out = x[np.argwhere(r[:,None]!=r)]
100 loops, best of 3: 12.9 ms per loop

In [388]: %%timeit
     ...: r = np.arange(len(x))
     ...: mask = r[:,None]!=r
     ...: out = cartesian_product_transpose(x,x)[mask.ravel()]
100 loops, best of 3: 16.5 ms per loop

In [389]: %%timeit
     ...: n = len(x)
     ...: r = np.arange(n)
     ...: mask = r[:,None]!=r
     ...: c0 = np.broadcast_to(x[:,None], (n, n))[mask]
     ...: c1 = np.broadcast_to(x, (n,n))[mask]
     ...: out = np.column_stack((c0,c1))
100 loops, best of 3: 6.72 ms per loop
```

Comment: Thanks! Is this scalable, as seems to be suggested by tom10?

Comment: @StatsSorceress Should be!

Comment: @StatsSorceress Added timings for all posted approaches on a 1000 elems array.

Answer (score 0):

This is a case where, unless you really need to speed, etc, of numpy, pure Python gives a cleaner solution:

```
import itertools

y = itertools.permutations([0, 1, 2], 2)

# [(0, 1), (0, 2), (1, 0), (1, 2), (2, 0), (2, 1)]
```

Comment: Thanks! I prefer scalable solutions, as this was just an MWE.